# If $0^\circ\leqslant x<360^\circ$, what is the maximum number of solutions to the equation $\sin x = a$ where a is a real number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

I tried solving the question, but I kept getting $5$ solutions. My book only has $4$ choices: $0$, $1$, $2$, or $3$ solutions. My solutions were $0^\circ$, $90^\circ$, $150^\circ$, $180^\circ$, and $270^\circ$. What did I do wrong? Why is $2$ solutions the correct answer?

Comment: $\sin 0=0\ne 1=\sin 90.$ So your solution is not correct. But $\sin 0=\sin 180=\sin 360.$

Comment: Draw a graph of the sine function and consider the points where a horizontal line will intersect it. That should help you to clarify what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, we need $-1\le a\le1$ for at least one real solution

If $\sin x_1=\sin x_2$
Using [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html), $$\sin x_1-\sin x_2=2\sin\dfrac{x_1-x_2}2\cos\dfrac{x_1+x_2}2.$$

If $\sin\dfrac{x_1-x_2}2=0\implies\dfrac{x_1-x_2}2=m180^\circ\iff x_1\equiv x_2\pmod{360^\circ}.$

If $\cos\dfrac{x_1+x_2}2=0\implies\dfrac{x_1+x_2}2=(2n+1)90^\circ\iff x_1\equiv 180^\circ- x_2\pmod{360^\circ}$

Now $x_1,x_2$ will coincide if $x_1\equiv 180^\circ- x_1\pmod{360^\circ}\iff x_1\equiv90^\circ\pmod{180^\circ}.$

In that case, we shall have only one in-congruent solution $\pmod{360^\circ}.$

Otherwise, there will be distinct two namely, $x_1,180^\circ- x_1.$

Answer (score 0):

For intuition, @Mark Bennet's visual approach in the comments is very helpful.

The solution of $\sin(x) = a$ can have a different number of solutions, depending on the value of $a$:

- $-1<a<1$ : 2 solutions
- $a=1$ or $a=-1$: 1 solution (either $x = 90^\circ$ or $270^\circ$, since we only get the local maximum or the minimum)
- $a>1$ or $a<-1$: 0 solutions, since $\sin$ only takes values in $[-1,1]$ for real arguments.

Answer: Hence, the maximum number of solutions is $2$.

Visualization for $a = -0.3$ (green), $a = 0.7$ (orange), $a = 1$ (red), and $a = 1.3$ (purple). [image]

The $x$-value(s) of the intersection(s) of a horizontal line at height $a$ with the sine-graph are the desired solutions of $\sin x = a$.

The number of solutions for given $a$ is the number of times the corresponding line intersects the sine-graph.

Comment: Note that there cannot be 3 solutions since OP states the domain does not include $360$. He says "$0\leq x < 360$".

Comment: Sorry I fixed it. The answer is 2 solutions, but I'm still trying to understand...

Comment: I misread, thanks - I have edited it.

Comment: So, does this question have multiple answers depending on the value of a? Because the question only says a is a real number. Also, why can't x=150 if 0.5 is a real number?

Comment: The equation can have a different number of solutions, depending on $a$, however the maximum number of solutions is 2.

Comment: How did you get −1<a<1 = 2 solutions?

Comment: I think I've got it now. Is the answer 2 solutions because each value of a only has 2 solutions to it?

Comment: For every $a$ there are *at most* 2 solutions of the equation (see also the edit below my plot).

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. I understand now.

Answer (score -1):

By definition, the sine of an angle $\theta$ is the $y$-coordinate of a point where the line through the origin that makes an angle of $\theta$ to the $x$-axis intersects the unit circle.  That's kind of a mouthful...

Let's try this:  given an angle $\theta$, draw a line through the origin that makes an angle of $\theta$ with the $x$-axis (measuring anti-clockwise).  That line will cross the unit circle somewhere.  The place where the line and circle cross is a point with coordinates $(x_{\theta},y_{\theta})$ (where the subscripts indicate that the coordinates have something to do with $\theta$).  By definition, $\sin(\theta) = y_{\theta}$.

So... suppose that we know that $\sin(\theta) = a$.  How many lines through the origin are there that intersect the unit circle at a height of $a$?  Each of those points corresponds to a solution of $\sin(\theta) = a$.  The collection of all points of height $a$ is a horizontal line.  How many times can such a horizontal line cross the circle?

Can you figure it out now?