# Good way of explaining how to find all solutions to $\sin\theta+a=0$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm not sure exactly how to properly describe this trigonometry problem, so I will just write it out. It is less of a "problem" and more of a "I can't find a really good way to explain it".

We want to find a value $\theta$ such that $$\sin\theta + a = 0,$$ where $|a| < 1$. Subtracting $a$ from both sides gives us $\sin\theta = -a$, and one solution is easily seen to be $\theta = \arcsin(-a)$. However, because $-1 < -a < 1$, there should be two possible values of $\theta$ that give $\sin\theta = -a$. I'll call the one we already found $\theta_1$, and the one we are looking for $\theta_2$.

The best explanation I could think of is, when looking at the unit circle, $\sin\theta_1$ is considered the $y$ coordinate on the circle, while $\cos\theta_1$ is the corresponding $x$ coordinate. However, if you reflected across the $y$ axis, that other angle will also satisfy $\sin\theta_2 = -a$. This reflection across the $y$ axis corresponds to $\theta_2 = \pi - \theta_1$, and this is correct, because $$\sin\theta_2 = \sin(\pi - \theta_1) = \sin\pi + \sin\theta_1 = 0 -a = -a.$$ So we have our two solutions: $$\theta_1 = \arcsin(-a) \\ \theta_2 = \pi - \arcsin(-a).$$

My problem is I feel like my solution is too "wordy" and not elegant enough. Maybe it's not possible, but is there a better, more analytic way of deriving this result? Since $|\arctan x| \le \pi/2$, I feel like it would be impossible to easily derive $\theta_2$ like we did $\theta_1$, since $|\theta_2| \ge \pi/2$, so there is no way for $\arctan x$ to ever map to that value.

Comment: If you reflect along the $x$ axis then the value of the $y$ coordinate changes. I think you're looking for the reflection across the $y$ axis.

Comment: The general solution to the equation $\sin x=\sin\alpha$ with all coterminal solutions is $x=n\pi+(-1)^n\alpha$  for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}.$ And the graph of $y=\sin x$ is the way I like think about this solution.

Comment: @CyclotomicField yes, that is a typo. I meant to say what you said. Thanks

Comment: @Bumblebee could you elaborate a bit on that solution? Or maybe point me in the right direction of how that solution came to be? I understand the answer myself, I am just struggling to elegantly explain it.

Comment: @AidenKenny: See the below answer. That is exactly what I was talking about.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380284/if-0-circ-leqslant-x360-circ-what-is-the-maximum-number-of-solutions-to-th/2380308#2380308

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of deriving this result is graphically: if we plot the graphs $y = \sin x$ and $y=a$, we see the following behaviour

[image]

It's easy to infer a pattern from this graph: $a$ equals $\sin x$ when $$x \in \{... -\pi - \arcsin a, 0 + \arcsin a, \pi - \arcsin a, 2\pi + \arcsin a ...\}$$

the pattern is thus
$$x = n\pi + (-1)^n \arcsin a, n \in Z$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $y = \arcsin a $

So we have,

$$\sin x + \sin y = 2\sin\frac{x+y}{2} \cos\frac{x-y}{2} = 0 \Rightarrow \sin\frac{x+y}{2} 
 =0 \text{ or }\cos\frac{x-y}{2} = 0  $$
$$x+y = \text{even multiple of }\pi \text{ or } x - y = \text{odd multiple of }\pi$$

$$ \color{blue}x = \begin{cases}\text{even multiple of }\pi  - y \\\text{or} \\\text{odd multiple of }\pi + y\end{cases} = n\pi + (-1)^ny = \color{blue}{n\pi + (-1)^n\arcsin a} , n \in \Bbb Z$$